# Clean logs in terminal when running detox test

Tags: react-native, detox

when I'm running `detox test` I got a lot of logs in the terminal and it's quite boring... and also not relevant informations. 
It looks like this : 
[image]

I basically want to hide all the `[INFO] AppleSimUtils` which are useless...

Any ideas about how to achieve that ? Thanks for the help !